# How to check the speed of a Gif?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, html5-video, gif

[image]

I have this Gif which appears to be normal but when I convert this to a video `mp4` to reduce the page load. The video plays in loop and it looks really choppy and too fast. Is there anyway to test if the speed of this gif is normal and adjust that to the video once it's converted?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question

Comment: I have the same question. Thank you for asking. The answer is not satisfactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks too fast to me in my browser.  There are usually options in the video converter to adjust the speed, depending on what you are using.

If you want to adjust the gif itself, try [this](http://ezgif.com/speed).

Comment: That website currently does not display the speed of the gif file.

Answer (score 0):

Using ffmpeg to extract the gif will usually give you the runtime of the gif and the number of frames extracted

```
frame= 2000 fps=133 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:03:20.00 bitrate=N/A speed=13.3x
```

**Command used to extract gif** make sure to have the output directory made first

```
ffmpeg -i "gifname.gif" -vsync 0 "output/%d.png"
```

**Step 1**
Read the time and the frames extracted.
In this case we have hh:mm:ss.millisecond. So it's 3 mins &  20 secs (200 secs).

**Step 2**
Calculate the duration of each frame by dividing the runtime with the number of frames. In this case it's 0.1 secs which means 10 frames were played within a second. This way we can find the fps of the gif (10 fps).

**Step 3**
We can now encode the video

```
ffmpeg -r 10 -i "output/%d.png" "out.mp4"
```

`-r` is used to set the fps

This is a very simple method and you can notice that the thumbnail for the video is usually corrupt. It it is better to reencode the video first to make sure that it will work for other devices as well.